# webservice(.asmx) issue

Tags: winforms, asmx

i have a webmethod in my webservice

```
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public int ADD(int a,int b )
    {
        return a+b;
    }

}
```

i need to implement it in a windowapplication which contain a textbox .i added webreference there with foldername "localhost" and URL as "http://localhost:4484/WebSite2/Service.asmx"

```
using WindowsApplication4.localhost;

   localhost.Service s = new Service();
    s.ADD(12,34);
    textBox1.Text = s.ToString();
```

but i am getting result as "WindowsApplication4.localhost.Service"  instead of "46"
Can any one tell me the reason for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
s.ADD(12,34);
textBox1.Text = s.ToString();
```

be

`textbox1.Text = s.ADD(12, 34).ToString();` ?